# parsedate after getDate method in jquery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I have this code currently:

```
   $('#cal').datepicker({
                    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      var dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function
      var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ); //the getDate method

   }
                });
```

I wanted to know how I can call parseDate on dateAsObject to format it as such: YYYY/MM/DD. To store  into mysql DATE field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct date formatter in `JavaScript`. You can either use any jQuery plugin to format the date as per your required format or you can just use this code to get the date formatted as per your requirement.

```
dateAsObject.getFullYear()+"/"+(dateAsObject.getMonth()+1)+"/"+ dateAsObject.getDate()
```

Comment: this works BECAUSE: getDate method returns a JavaScript Date-object, which exposes getter-functions. I like @AlexC answer better though. No need to convert from string to Date-object and back :)

Comment: @TopiOjala - Check my comment for AlexC's answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can add this :

**dateFormat: '{dateFormat}'**

```
     $('#cal').datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
         onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
         var dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function

       }
     });
```

Comment: I think the OP wants date in that format only to store in DB but not in the UI. By setting the dateFormat as `YYYY/MM/DD` the plugin will display the date also in that format.

Comment: yeah, that is very true. He has a choice at least