# C# - The value 'dd/mm/yyyy' is not valid for Value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, datetime

I want to use date format as `dd/mm/yyyy` in my application.

I have a model as follows -

```
public class PatientDetailModel
{
    [Display(Name = "OPH_GOS1_SightTestDate", ResourceType = typeof(Ophthalmic))]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime SightTestDate { get; set; }
}
```

and view -

```
 @Html.LabelFor(p => p.SightTestDate)
    <div class="display-flex">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SightTestDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", autocomplete = "off", placeholder = "dd/mm/yyyy", id = "txtSightTestDate" })
 </div>
```

Jquery code -

```
 $("#txtSightTestDate").datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', autoclose: true });
```

This is showing me date in format as `dd/mm/yyyy` but when i submit the page, it gives me an error as -

> The value `15/08/2017` is not valid for SIGHT TEST DATE.

It looks like while submitting, its taking format as `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: Is this a client side error (you need to reconfigure the `$.validator`) or a server side error (the culture of your app must also accept dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format or you need a custom ModelBinder)

Comment: it does not look like that it's taking format of mm/dd/yyyy as the clearly states: 15/08/2017 is not valid. if it was changing the format, then the error should have been 08/15/2017.

Comment: [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] remove this and try again that will do

Comment: @omkar-patade which .datepicker jquery API are you using?

Comment: I think this answer might work as it is for your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16885042/2048391 The trick is to use a hidden date element that's been cloned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying cultureInfo with datetimeformat in Global.asax file worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

there is a work around for your scenario on model define the string property and on post back parse your date from said format.

or

debug your client side code or use to shuffle format with different combinations like yyyy/MM/dd if it working then your jquery plugin have parsing issue.